# How to get user ids from Cognos Audit report?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-8

I am able to retrieve the usernames stored in cogipf_userlogon tables but I am not able to retrieve the usernames.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add Query Item COGIPF_USERNAME from COGIPF_USERLOGON to your report.